Schedule conditional periodic notifications in Flutter (Dart)
In my Flutter (Dart) app, I want to periodically schedule a notification only if a certain condition is met.
Can it be done?

"Every morning - check if rain is expected today, and if so - trigger a
notification to bring an umbrella"

I currently use flutter_local_notifications, and in the docs I see that I can use either zonedSchedule or periodicallyShow, but looks like none of them support condition check before each notification occurence.
I prefer to keep using local notifications, and not use an external tool where I have to manage all the user's notification.
Thanks!

This sounds more like triggering a daily background task that then happens to possibly show a notification, so I recommend looking at some of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+triggering+a+daily+background+task
